# Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass when installing cloud_firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a MacBook Air M1 and it appears the problem stems from that, I've been battling this problem for a few days with no hope in sight, my flutter application runs fine until I run "flutter pub add cloud_firestore". When I do that I'm presented with the error below, which gets outputted when pod install is running. I have tried many different solutions from here and on GitHub, including:
-Using sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi and arch -x86_64 pod install
-Reinstalling cocoapods using homebrew and gem
-Using a different ruby version or environment
-Creating a new project

All other packages except cloud_firestore work

The error(some parts of CDN relative path trunk have been excluded because of body char limit):

````
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of the target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Finding Podfile changes
      A cloud_firestore
      - Flutter
      - connectivity_plus
      - firebase_analytics
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - firebase_database
      - google_sign_in_ios
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '9.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `connectivity_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
    firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '9.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '9.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '9.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_database` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`
    firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '9.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/ios`
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_4_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/6.2.2/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/9.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/9.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_d_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/d/6/ReachabilitySwift/5.0.0/ReachabilitySwift.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/9.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/9.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/9.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/9.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_9_f.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/9.3.0/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_b_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/9.3.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_3_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/9.3.0/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/6.2.2/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_b_b_9.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/b/b/9/AppAuth/1.5.0/AppAuth.podspec.json exists! Ret.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/7.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
 
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.24/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    ――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
    ### Command
    ```
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod install --verbose
    ```
    ### Report
    * What did you do?
    * What did you expect to happen?
    * What happened instead?
    ### Stack
    ```
       CocoaPods : 1.11.3
            Ruby : ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [arm64-darwin21]
        RubyGems : 3.3.11
            Host : macOS 12.5 (21G72)
           Xcode : 13.4.1 (13F100)
             Git : git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)
    Ruby lib dir : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib
    Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
    ```
    ### Plugins
    ```
    cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
    cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
    cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
    cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
    cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
    ```
    ### Podfile
    ```ruby
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    platform :ios, '12.0'
    # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
    ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
    project 'Runner', {
      'Debug' => :debug,
      'Profile' => :release,
      'Release' => :release,
    }
    def flutter_root
      generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
      unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
        raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
      end
      File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
        matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
        return matches[1].strip if matches
      end
      raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
    end
    require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)
    flutter_ios_podfile_setup
    target 'Runner' do
      use_frameworks!
      use_modular_headers!
      flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    end
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      end
    end
    ```
    ### Error
    ```
    JSON::ParserError - 859: unexpected token at '{
      "name": "BoringSSL-GRPC",
      "version": "0.0.24",
      "summary": "BoringSSL is a fork of OpenSSL that is designed to meet Google's needs.",
      "description": "BoringSSL is a fork of OpenSSL designed to meet Google's needs.\n\nAlthough BoringSSL is an open source project, it is not intended for general use, as OpenSSL is.\nWe don't recommend that third parties depend upon it. Doing so is likely to be frustrating\nbecause there are no guarantees of API stability. Only the latest version of this pod is\nsupported, and every new version is a new major version.\n\nWe update Google libraries and programs that use BoringSSL as needed when deciding to make API\nchanges. This allows us to mostly avoid compromises in the name of compatibility. It works for\nus, but it may not work for you.\n\nAs a Cocoapods pod, it has the advantage over OpenSSL's pods that the library doesn't need to\nbe precompiled. This eliminates the 10 - 20 minutes of wait the first time a user does \"pod\ninstall\", letting it be used as a dynamic framework (pending solution of Cocoapods' issue #4605),\nand works with bitcode automatically. It's also thought to be smaller than OpenSSL (which takes\n1MB - 2MB per ARM architecture), but we don't have specific numbers yet.\n\nBoringSSL arose because Google used OpenSSL for many years in various ways and, over time, built\nup a large number of patches that were maintained while tracking upstream OpenSSL. As Google's\nproduct portfolio became more complex, more copies of OpenSSL sprung up and the effort involved\nin maintaining all these patches in multiple places grew steadily.\n\nCurrently BoringSSL is the SSL library in Chrome/Chromium, Android (but it's not part of the\nNDK), and a number of other apps/programs.",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/google/boringssl",
      "license": {
        "type": "Mixed",
        "file": "LICENSE"
      },
      "authors": [
        "Adam Langley",
        "David Benjamin",
        "Matt Braithwaite"
      ],
      "source": {
        "git": "https://github.com/google/boringssl.git",
        "commit": "b9232f9e27e5668bc0414879dcdedb2a59ea75f2"
      },
      "platforms": {
        "ios": "9.0",
        "osx": "10.10",
        "tvos": "10.0",
        "watchos": "4.0"
      },
      "module_name": "openssl_grpc",
      "header_mappings_dir": "src/include/openssl",
      "header_dir": "openssl_grpc",
      "module_map": "src/include/openssl/BoringSSL.modulemap",
      "compiler_flags": [
        "-DOPENSSL_NO_ASM",
        "-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS",
        "-w",
        "-DBORINGSSL_PREFIX=GRPC"
      ],
      "requires_arc": false,
      "prepare_command": "set -e\n# Add a module map and an umbrella header\nmkdir -p src/include/openssl\ncat > src/include/openssl/umbrella.h <<EOF\n  #include \"ssl.h\"\n  #include \"crypto.h\"\n  #include \"aes.h\"\n  /* The following macros are defined by base.h. The latter is the first file included by the\n     other headers. */\n  #if defined(OPENSSL_ARM) || defined(OPENSSL_AARCH64)\n  #  include \"arm_arch.h\"\n  #endif\n  #include \"asn1.h\"\n  #include \"asn1_mac.h\"\n  #include \"asn1t.h\"\n  #include \"blowfish.h\"\n  #include \"cast.h\"\n  #include \"chacha.h\"\n  #include \"cmac.h\"\n  #include \"conf.h\"\n  #include \"cpu.h\"\n  #include \"curve25519.h\"\n  #include \"des.h\"\n  #include \"dtls1.h\"\n  #include \"hkdf.h\"\n  #include \"md4.h\"\n  #include \"md5.h\"\n  #include \"obj_mac.h\"\n  #include \"objects.h\"\n  #include \"opensslv.h\"\n  #include \"ossl_typ.h\"\n  #include \"pkcs12.h\"\n  #include \"pkcs7.h\"\n  #include \"pkcs8.h\"\n  #include \"poly1305.h\"\n  #include \"rand.h\"\n  #include \"rc4.h\"\n  #include \"ripemd.h\"\n  #include \"safestack.h\"\n  #include \"srtp.h\"\n  #include \"x509.h\"\n  #include \"x509v3.h\"\nEOF\ncat > src/include/openssl/BoringSSL.modulemap <<EOF\n  framework module openssl {\n    umbrella header \"umbrella.h\"\n    textual header \"arm_arch.h\"\n    export *\n    module * { export * }\n  }\nEOF\n\n# To avoid symbol conflict with OpenSSL, gRPC needs to rename all the BoringSSL symbols with a\n# prefix. This is done with BoringSSL's BORINGSSL_PREFIX mechanism\n# (https://github.com/google/boringssl/blob/75148d7abf12bdd1797fec3c5da9a21963703516/BUILDING.md#building-with-prefixed-symbols).\n# The required prefix header file boringssl_prefix_symbols.h is not part of BoringSSL repo at\n# this moment. It has to be generated by BoringSSL's users and be injected to BoringSSL build.\n# gRPC generates this file in script /tools/distrib/upgrade_boringssl_objc.sh. This script\n# outputs a gzip+base64 encoded version of boringssl_prefix_symbols.h because of Cocoapods'\n# limit on the 'prepare_command' field length. The encoded header is generated from\n# /src/boringssl/boringssl_prefix_symbols.h. Here we decode the content and inject the header to\n# the correct location in BoringSSL.\ncase \"$(uname)\" in\n  Darwin) opts=\"\" ;;\n       *) opts=\"--ignore-garbage\" ;;\nesac\nbase64 --decode $opts <<EOF | gunzip > src/include/openssl/boringssl_prefix_symbols.h\n  H4sICAAAAAAC/2JvcmluZ3NzbF9wcmVmaXhfc3ltYm9scy5oAKydXXPbuJZo3+dXuO683Kk6NRM7nW73\n  fVNsJdG0Y/tIck9nXliURNk8oUiFoOy4f/0FQErEx94g94arTs10LK21KQDEF0Hgv/7r7DErszptss3Z\n  6vX0j2RV1Xn5KESR7Otsm/9MnrJ0k9X/KZ7OqvLso/50sbg5W1e7Xd78v7PV7xfvL7a/Zxe/ZR9+/fVy\n  tX73y/kvl7/9vllvss3qIv3we5b+9mF78W//9l//dXZV7V/r/PGpOfu/6/84u3h3fvmPs89V9VhkZ7Ny\n  /Z/yK+pb91m9y4XIZbymOjuI7B8y2v71H2e7apNv5f9Py81/VfXZJhdNna8OTXbWPOXiTFTb5iWts7Ot\n  /DAtX5Vrf6j3lcjOXvJG/oBa///q0Jxts+xMIk9ZnalfX6elTIh/nO3r6jmXFy6FaSP/T3aWrqrnTJnW\n  p2svqyZfZ+oq2rj7/nqPH+33WVqf5eVZWhSKzDNx/HXLL9Ozxd2n5f9M5tOz2eLsfn735+x6en32fyYL\n  +e//cza5vdZfmjwsv9zNz65ni6ubyezr4mxyc3MmqfnkdjmbLpTrf2bLL2fz6efJXCJ3kpK+3n17dfNw\n  Pbv9rMHZ1/ubmYzSC87uPinH1+n86ov8y+Tj7Ga2/KbDf5otb6eLxX9Kx9nt3dn0z+nt8mzxRXmMK/s4\n  PbuZTT7eTM8+yX9Nbr8p3eJ+ejWb3PxDXvd8erX8h1Qc/0t+6erudjH954PUye+cXU++Tj6rC9H08Z/6\n  h32ZLBd3Mu5c/rzFw81S/YxP87uvZzd3C3XlZw+LqYwxWU4ULdNQXvLiH5Kbygucq+ueyP9dLWd3t8on\n  ARl6OZ+o67idfr6ZfZ7eXk0Ve6eB5d1cfvdh0TH/OJvMZwsV9O5hqeg75dRF+O72dqq/06a+Sg95Lfoq\n  pnOZEF8nWvzJzo3/1OX/491cOuXtk0yur5P7+fTT7K+zfSqaTJw1L9WZLHplk2/zrBay8MjCX5WZzIRG\n  FTFZqHdC/UGJ8kbdrarEVduzXbquq7Ps5z4tdSGU/8sbcZbWj4ed9ImzVSbhTAeSd+9//tu/b+SdXWbg\n  5fzf9B9nq/8AP0pm8qfP2y8EHeYXz9Kzf//3s0T9n9W/9dTsLtkmspaBr6H/Y/uHf/TAf1gOkTVUS4f0\n  nuvlzSJZF7lMqmSXyephM1bnk46VoQM9Iqufs5qjs0jHqurCZHXYbmVx47gB3o7wfJ5c8FPWpwE7U4v6\n  2Cnt0549JiXC6fAoy3ST7zLVstG8BulZn2QLV2RMsQ17blYiIL8+Js/COabqirzMmzwtjr8k2Ry6mpca\n  CFf1cafzeVJU6SZRBtW7kV2xsYEgtjff3U9v1QfqGihVpsv1xvvp16TOungL2V1QbeJIK8QC5lVeRdkd\n  3o7wUstWlKv3YMgdcfmgoI+h/ng1u5c9l2STiXWd7ylFEqZBu6of0oOs58t8w9CbOOpfqd4Kz61Q1LvO\n  97J/H3HlvQCNsckfM9FExOgFaAy2O+D8/jMp013GFHd00M6+6hZG3bv0ZyKrbMEr744Bj5KXsVF6Axol\n  IguC6b+vtxEZ0NEBe9VU66pIIiKcDGiUeruOSZ8jjvqf0+LAlWsWN0eVm1CZyUWSynaNYe5IzLoqqvX3\n  rr7j2U0DGEU0skeY1htuplq8E+Hu632SbjbJutrt60xPxRC7gwMaIN62zjLgm4IcERMBMWX5eEdPP4uE\n  rW/yQxAPEjHfsALkG8THTRYoVZZ/qXLwLlk/pbIWX2d1QzL7OOg/j/OfD/n1J1aOpMUjIxDoQSK2w9Sr\n  CSvMEYbd2c+mTuOSzHPAkUT7MzkBOtT3rp8yWT/u6/xZzbJ/z16pdk8AxGj7q/K3PdbVYU+OYOOAv8jS\n  2kg9QY7gCrAYbj4xI3kaLN6u2mS8EIrErJUeVzGvvYN9d1amqyJLqrXYq0ZxX8iBPjUE5EAjifyxzLpa\n  QE1dSGC3F8yQsAyN3RRC5V9ZZuTuJibxY22Lg3g63rrkH2bTgF2272SnZHyTbsRVyuXbfC1rAarV5bEI\n  6n7huRUZsvJuZpdHIuzTOt2x3JrErG2Ny6ixHRz0tzeCaNTzGbreoBG7rtIFS92iiPfYVCdFLhqW3jLA\n  UeSf0kMhh4upEC+yzlhxAnmSkbGSg8jqTdqkbxL0ZIOjZz8TbqgORb1l9iKb9E32kyk/8ViEyJYalMCx\n  8nJbJeu0KFbp+jsnjiWAY8gbtageo6I4CjiOmoTSdy/3BrIEeAw91cKaksAkSCyZdfGxXAkSi9FbO3Kw\n  kdlTM1DY++OQq8fNT4dmU72wksQ2wFH0s470iToz5NGwvevZyPIshyDstPctcDTi00YARbyFkLWM/M76\n  e3uLsjLbt8DRZPHNt69RtYijCMbZZPvmKSKI5oMRuNlu4L5fP63svlFU65R1D4ISP1aZyVFHs9sn8wV5\n  csJkIfMLXfjie+psVz1n3Mk'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/json/common.rb:216:in `parse'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/json/common.rb:216:in `parse'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:748:in `from_string'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:722:in `from_file'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:188:in `specification'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:58:in `block in specification_name'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `each'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `specification_name'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:216:in `search'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in `create_set_from_sources'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in `specifications_for_dependency'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in `block in sort_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in `sort_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:744:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:727:in `activate_new_spec'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
    ```
    ――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
    [!] Oh no, an error occurred.
    Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
    Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md
    Don't forget to anonymize any private data!
    Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
          report.issues = results['items'].map { |item| Issue.new(item) }
                                          ^^^^
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12.
Exited
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have found a fix after days, nothing worked until I deleted all the pods using `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk` and after a long pod install everything worked and I am able to access firestore.